# Как для одной переменной назначить разные класса в зависимости от условия

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как для одной переменной назначить разные типы
Пример есть несколько классов City1 и City2 c одинаковой структурой
String name;
String id;

Где-то в программе, в другом классе, есть метод

```
public void outData(String type){
        Class c = null;

        MyResponce myResponce = GetResponce();
        Object obj = null;

        if(type.equals("City1")){
            try {
                obj = Class.forName("com.api_model.City1").newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            City1 myClass = (City1) obj;
            myClass = (City1)myResponce.getBody();
        }
        if(type.equals("City2")){
            try {
                obj = Class.forName("com.api_model.City2").newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            City2 myClass = (City2) obj;
            myClass = (City2)myResponce.getBody();
        }

        //Некие действия с классом CityN в которых все методы одинаковы
        Log.i("tester", "Name: "+myClass.getName());  //Здесь ошибка
        Log.i("tester", "Id: "+myClass.getId());  //Здесь ошибка
    }
```

Вопрос: как получить метод myClass.getName()? И вообще - как правильно поступать в таких ситуациях, когда есть множество однотипных классов и надо создать однотипную операцию. Не делать же для каждого класса свой метод outDataCity1...outDataCityN

Comment: Может не в тему, но почему бы не сократить все `catch` до `catch (Exception e) ` ? Все равно компилятор покажет и назовет ошибку... Может я и не прав

Comment: ВОЗМОЖНО надо добавить методы `getID()` и `getName()` туда же, где есть метод `forName()`

Comment: Для вашего случая идеально подойдет паттерн фасад.

Answer (score 1):

1. Прочитать про код стайл в джаве что бы создавать правильно пакеты.
2. Создать один класс `City` с нужными полями и радоваться жизни.

И вообще поучить Джаву с нуля про объекты и остальное.

Comment: Вопрос о том, как обратиться к методам класса используя Class.forName, getMethod, invike и тд Пример чисто условный, в реальном проекте все намного сложнее

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел в Java Reflection вот здесь http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api